# In a javascript heavy website, how can I redirect users to a different page, while also loading javascripts, without using GET parameters?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a website that's more of an application, with two pages. It's incredibly javascript heavy and most of the times the two pages have nothing to do with each other.

However, recently I've had the need to be able to send users from one page to the other. Not only that, I want to load certain javascript functions after the redirect has been made. I know I can set a bunch of URL parameters after the page redirect, that will describe what to load, but I want the url clean.

**Example:**

I have two pages: Employee profile (employee.php) and Tasks (tasks.php). When an admin is logged in and viewing tasks.php he sees a list over different tasks the employees have in a table. The usernames are then clickable and when an admin clicks the user I want the following to happen:

1. Redirect the user from tasks.php to employee.php
2. Run the JS-function loadUserProfile(id);

How can I achieve this without using GET parameters? Is there a general best practice way of cross application navigation I should be aware of?

Comment: How to make one page aware of info from another without server logic and without passing data from one to the other? I would say you're out of luck, but have you looked into [DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) ?

Comment: I can’t see any sensible reason here that would speak against using a GET parameter to pass the id … but if you explicitly want to make things more complicated, you could … use a POST form instead, or store the id in sessionStorage (as Anthony already mentioned), in a cookie, in window.name, …

Comment: @CBroe, The problem with GET is that it makes the URL long and ugly. My example was just to illustrate my point. My real life example would've contained a lot more parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `POST`. Basically you need to dynamically create a form similar to `<form aciton="employee.php" method="post"/>`, fill it with the data you need, and submit it.

That being said `GET` sounds like the more appropriate method to use. `POST` usually modifies data. If you want cleaner URLs, you can use `mod_rewrite`.